# installing Amazon DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan 0.5.4

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan

Im trying to install and run Amazon DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan 0.5.4 locally, and I followed the instruction [here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/0.5.4/README.md) on linux ubuntu but I got Titan 1.0.0 instead of Titan 0.5.4 which I really couldn't find why!

```
phoenix@ dynamodb-titan-storage-backend$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                                       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Amazon DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan 1.0.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to switch from `1.0.0` to `0.5.4`branch.

To do that, run this after cloning your repo:

```
git checkout 0.5.4
```

Comment: When you're sure that solved your problem, don't forget to mark my solution as an accepted answer. ;)